# linux grep pattern in an unknown number of column

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file with many rows and columns and I want to grep a column by the 'column name'.

```
    M121    M125    M123    M124    M131    M126    M211    N
0.41463252  1.00296561  -0.1713496  0.15923644  -1.49682602 -1.9478695  1.45223392  …
-0.46775802 0.14591103  1.122446    0.83648981  -0.3038532  -1.1841548  2.18074729  …
0.67736835  2.12969375  -0.8187298  0.13582824  -1.49290987 -0.6798428  1.04353114  …
0.08673344  -0.40437672 1.8441559   -0.63679375 0.47998832  0.1702844   0.54029264  …
-0.32606297 -0.95551833 0.6157599   0.02819133  1.44818627  -0.9528659  0.09207864  …
-0.51781121 0.88806507  -0.2913757  -0.00463802 0.05037374  0.953773    0.01244763  …
-0.25724472 0.05119051  0.2109025   -0.26083822 -0.52094072 -0.938595   -0.01275275 …
1.94348766  -1.83607523 1.2010512   -0.54109756 -0.88323831 -0.6263788  -0.96973544 …
0.1900408   -0.61025656 0.4586306   -0.69181051 -0.90713834 0.3589271   0.6870383   …
0.54866057  -0.03861159 -1.505861   0.54871682  -0.24602601 -0.3941754  0.85673905  …
```

for example, I want to grep M211 column but I don't know the number of column. I tried:

```
awk '$i == "M211"' filename or  awk '$0 == "M211"' filename
```

awk: illegal field $(), name "i"
 input record number 1, filename
 source line number 1

Is there any solution ? Thank you.

Comment: Why would you for your example pick a column name, M211, to "grep" that doesn't exist in your sample input?

Comment: @EdMorton I have many columns behind and one of them is M211, if I pick M121 or M125, I am afraid that I will get the answer is awk '$1 == "M121"' filename or awk '$2 == "M125"' filename which is not the answer I want. I would like to have the answer that I didn't know the number of column but can pick the column by the 'column name'. Thanks.

Comment: How does choosing a column name that doesn't exist for your example help with that? You're missing the expected output that's required for asking a question here (see [ask]) because the expected output given your posted sample input and command line is nothing. Giving us a command to test with that produces no output given the input you've provided to test against makes no sense - choose a value that does exist so you can show meaningful expected output in your question and we have something concrete to test against. Right now we're just guessing at what your desired output is.

Comment: @EdMorton thats helpful !

Comment: Good, now if you [edit] your question to do what I suggest it will then contain the [mcve] required to get upvotes and help clarify your requirements.

Comment: @EdMorton I changed a column into M211

Comment: Just changing your command line to use a column name that existed in your original input would've been preferable so we didn't all have to now change the sample input we copied from your question to test against but OK. Now just add the expected output given that input and your command line and you've got a complete question.

Comment: btw if your awk really produced the error message `awk: illegal field $(), name "i" input record number 1, filename source line number 1` given either of the commands you posted (`awk '$i == "M211"' filename` or `awk '$0 == "M211"' filename`) then your awk is severely broken and you should get a new one. I suspect you got that output from running some other command that you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {for(i=NF;i>0;i--) if($i=="M125") break; if(!i) exit} {print $i}' file
M125
1.00296561
0.14591103
2.12969375
-0.40437672
-0.95551833
0.88806507
0.05119051
-1.83607523
-0.61025656
-0.03861159
```

Explained:

```
NR==1 {                       # for the first record
    for(i=NF;i>0;i--)         # iterate fields backwards for change
        if($i=="M125") break  # until desired column, remember i
    if (!i) exit              # if column not found, exit
} 
{print $i}                    # print value from ith field
```

Comment: easy fix for the flaw: `awk 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if($i=="M125") break} if(i > NF) exit} {print $i}' file`

Comment: @Sundeep I was trying to save bytes... How about the backwards iterator for shorter `if()`? :D

Comment: Back to original, all those bytes! :(

Answer (score 3):

`awk` solution - iterates over column names for first line of input file and saves column number if it matches desired pattern. Then print that column. No output if match is not found

```
$ awk 'NR==1{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="M125")c=i;} if(c==0)exit; }
       {print $c}' ip.txt
M125
1.00296561
0.14591103
2.12969375
-0.40437672
-0.95551833
0.88806507
0.05119051
-1.83607523
-0.61025656
-0.03861159
```

Similar solution with `perl`

```
$ perl -lane '@i = grep {$F[$_] eq "M123"} 0..$#F if $.==1; exit if !@i;
              print @F[@i]' ip.txt
M123
-0.1713496
1.122446
-0.8187298
1.8441559
0.6157599
-0.2913757
0.2109025
1.2010512
0.4586306
-1.505861
```

- `@i = grep {$F[$_] eq "M123"} 0..$#F if $.==1` for the header line, get index for which column value matches the string `M123`
- `exit if !@i` exit if no match found
- `print @F[@i]` print the matched column
- assumes there'll be only one column match

for multiple matches, use

```
perl -lane '@i = grep {$F[$_] =~ /^(M121|M126)$/} 0..$#F if $.==1; exit if !@i;
            print join " ", @F[@i]' ip.txt
```

Comment: thanks, so is it that perl or python is easier for above manipulation ?

Comment: not much of a difference for this problem - awk is good enough and available with most unix like OS.. but if you have other text manipulations and automations to go with, probably python/perl would be better

Comment: No, awk is available on all UNIX installations and you are not better off with python or perl for other text manipulation - those are for if you're doing something OTHER than text manipulation.

Comment: I disagree, even for text manipulation, python/perl covers broader range of options and std + 3rd party modules to make it easier..

Comment: I understand your opinion but you are basing that on you not knowing awk very well. In 30+ years of manipulating text and helping others do so in multiple domains I've never found a use for python or perl for that task. Maybe there is some edge case out there I just haven't come across yet but its certainly false to state that in general "if you have other text manipulations and automations to go with, probably python/perl would be better"

Answer (score 1):

If you are more familiar with Python:

```
import csv
column_name = "M125"
with open("file", "rb") as f:
  data_dict = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=" ")
  print column_name
  for item in data_dict:
    print item[column_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

To do anything with columns ("fields" in awk) by name rather than number you should first create an array that maps the field name to number and from then on just access the fields using that array indexed by the field name(s) rather than accessing them directly by field number(s):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i} {print $(f["M124"])}' file
M124
0.15923644
0.83648981
0.13582824
-0.63679375
0.02819133
-0.00463802
-0.26083822
-0.54109756
-0.69181051
0.54871682
```

or if you don't want to hard-code the column name:

```
$ awk -v c=M124 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i} {print $(f[c])}' file
M124
0.15923644
0.83648981
0.13582824
-0.63679375
0.02819133
-0.00463802
-0.26083822
-0.54109756
-0.69181051
0.54871682
```

and to print any number of columns in the order you choose:

```
$ awk -v cols='M129 M124' 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i; n=split(cols,c)} {for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", $(f[c[i]]), (i<n ? OFS : ORS)}' file
M129 M124
1.45223392 0.15923644
2.18074729 0.83648981
1.04353114 0.13582824
0.54029264 -0.63679375
0.09207864 0.02819133
0.01244763 -0.00463802
-0.01275275 -0.26083822
-0.96973544 -0.54109756
0.6870383 -0.69181051
0.85673905 0.54871682
```